Why the tunneling amplitude between two quantum states is $\left<n\right|H\left|n'\right>$?
In Srednicki's QFT textbook eq.(93.5), the tunneling amplitude between two different quantum states $\left|n\right>$ and $\left|n'\right>$ is $\left<n\right|H\left|n'\right> \sim {\rm e}^{-S}$. ($S$ is the Euclidean action for a classical solution mediating between $\left|n\right>$ and $\left|n'\right>$).
Why the tunneling amplitude can be expressed as $\left<n\right|H\left|n'\right>$? Shouldn't it be something like $\left<n\right|{\rm e}^{-iHt}\left|n'\right>$?

Rate is something like amplitude and $\left < n | H | n' \right >$ is something like $\left < n | e^{-iHt} | n' \right >$.

Fermi's Golden rule.

@ConnorBehan Thanks. I agree $\left<n\right|{\rm e}^{-iHt}\left|n'\right> \sim {\rm e}^{-S}$. But here it is expressed as $\left<n\right|H\left|n'\right> \sim {\rm e}^{-S}$, which obviously represents the amplitude (i.e. probability), not the rate.  This is where I am confused.

@ConnorBehan. Thanks. I posted an answer myself.

Let me try to answer the question post by myself.
I went back to check Coleman's papers on the tunneling of false vacuum [1,2] ([2] with CG Callan Jr). The probability of tunneling per unit time per unit volume $\Gamma/V$ can be expressed as
$$
\Gamma/V = A {\rm e}^{-B/\hbar}(1+O(\hbar)) ~~~~~~~~~~~(1).
$$
$A$ and $B$ are two efficients. For the question post here, we only care about $B$.
The Lagrangian of a particle moving in 1D is $L = 1/2 \cdot \dot{q}^2 - V(q)$ where $q$ is the space coordinate. Then, it is known that
$$
B = \int_{q_i}^{q_f} dq \sqrt{V(q)}  ~~~~~~~~~~~(2).
$$
With a Wick rotation $\tau = it$, we have the Lagrangian in the Euclidean spacetime,
$$
L_E = \frac{1}{2} \frac{dq}{d\tau} \frac{dq}{d\tau} + V(q).
$$
This makes $L_E = -L$ and thus ${\rm e}^{-S_E} = {\rm e}^{-\int d\tau dq L_E} = {\rm e}^{iS}$.
Now we assume the particle energy is zero
$$
E = \frac{1}{2} \dot{q}^2 +V(q) = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{dq}{d\tau} \frac{dq}{d\tau} + V(q) = 0,
$$
Then we can further express Eq.~(2) as
$$
B = \int_{\tau_i}^{\tau_f} d\tau \frac{dq}{d\tau} \sqrt{V(q)}
= \int_{\tau_i}^{\tau_f} d\tau 2V(q) = \int_{\tau_i}^{\tau_f} d\tau (\frac{1}{2} \frac{dq}{d\tau} \frac{dq}{d\tau} + V(q))
=\int_{\tau_i}^{\tau_f} d\tau L_E = S_E. 
$$
Note that because we have used the constraint of $E = 0$, the above expression should be considered as a certain classical solution mediating the initial and the final state. Also, with ignoring some subtleties discussed in [1], I simply extend $\tau_i$ and $\tau_f$ to $\pm \infty$.
Now, combined with Eq.(1), we see that
$$
\Gamma/V \sim {\rm e}^{-S_E}.
$$
Also, I thank the comment of @Connor Behan that "Rate is something like amplitude and $\left<n\right| H  \left|n'\right>$
is something like ⟨|−|′⟩". This inspired me to think that analogous to the relation between tunneling rate $\Gamma$ and tunneling amplitude ${\rm e}^{-\Gamma t}$, naively $\left<n\right| H \left|n'\right>$ is the tunneling rate
$$
\left<n\right| H  \left|n'\right> \sim \Gamma \sim {\rm e}^{-S_E}.
$$
Some further thoughts. In the QFT language, $\left<n\right| {\rm e}^{-iHt}  \left|n'\right>$ is the generating function
$$
\left<n\right| {\rm e}^{-iHt}  \left|n'\right> \sim Z[\phi] = \int [D\phi] {\rm e}^{iS[\phi]}.
$$
We also know that generating function can be re-written as
$$
Z[\phi] = {\rm e}^{iW[\phi]}
$$
where $W[\phi]$ is can be understood as a collection of all connected Feynman diagrams,
$$
W[\phi] \sim \int d^d x V_{\rm eff}.
$$
Then we can infer that
$$
H \sim \int d^d x V_{\rm eff}
$$
Or in other words, ${\rm e}^{-S_E}$ contributes to the effective potential. This essentially connects with another famous paper of Coleman [3] (with E. Weinberg)
[1] Coleman S R. The fate of the false vacuum. 1. Semiclassical theory, 1977[J]. Phys. Rev. D, 15: 2929.
[2] Callan Jr C G, Coleman S. Fate of the false vacuum. II. First quantum corrections[J]. Physical Review D, 1977, 16(6): 1762.
[3] Coleman S, Weinberg E. Radiative corrections as the origin of spontaneous symmetry breaking[J]. Physical Review D, 1973, 7(6): 1888.
